# How can the Apache KARAF built-in Krb5LoginModule (JAAS) be application-specific?

Tags: ssh, active-directory, authentication, kerberos

I have an environment containing an Active Directory, a Windows client and an Apache KARAF with the built-in SSH server and a realm using the Krb5LoginModule (JAAS).

What I'm trying to do is to authenticate the client to the Active Directory and then make a passwordless authentication to the Apache KARAF over ssh with Putty.

I'm a bit curious how the Krb5LoginModule with a single keytab-file shall serve multiple applications over its single realm, since the keytab-file is application-specific (over its SPN) and with every tutorial I read so far you have to make changes in the application's config file.
E.g. you bind one SPN (HOST) in the keytab-file which serves an HTTP- and SSH-service. With my understanding the http-service cannot authenticate users since it needs HTTP as SPN.
E.g. an HTTP-Server sends back a negotiate-request back after receiving TGT, but in the server nothing is configured since the authentication is delegated to the LoginModule.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Partly I solved the riddle. A keytab-file can contain multiple pairs of Kerberos principals and encrypted keys.

See:

[Use a keytab](https://kb.iu.edu/d/aumh)

[Active Directory: Using Kerberos Keytabs to integrate non-Windows systems](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/36470.active-directory-using-kerberos-keytabs-to-integrate-non-windows-systems.aspx)